# Using mail merge with word 2013 to get data out of excel 2013

Tags: 2013, excel, word, office

We want to use mail merge in a word document which is saved in a sharepoint 2013 document library.

If we try to connect to an excel sheet which is also located in the same document library, we get the following error message:

> "We could not find your file..."

Is http and https in that case not supported?
Any workarounds?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: online or on prem version?

Comment: on premise version